# duplicate row based on another column python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
dt | ticker_like | text
12:16:17 | Ab | hello ab nice to meet you
12:16:18 | hey, you | hey I will be happy to meet you
```

I want to write a code depending on how many comma separated words are in the ticker_like, I want to duplicate them like this

```
dt | ticker_like | text
12:16:17 | Ab | hello ab nice to meet you
12:16:18 | hey | hey I will be happy to meet you
12:16:18 | you | hey I will be happy to meet you
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.explode`:

```py
df["ticker_like"] = df["ticker_like"].apply(
    lambda x: list(map(str.strip, x.split(",")))
)
df = df.explode("ticker_like").reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         dt ticker_like                             text
0  12:16:17          Ab        hello ab nice to meet you
1  12:16:18         hey  hey I will be happy to meet you
2  12:16:18         you  hey I will be happy to meet you
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Online Python compiler (interpreter) to run Python online.
# Write Python 3 code in this online editor and run it.
import pandas as pd
data = {'dt':['12:16:17', '12:16:18'],
        'ticker_like':['Ab','Hey,you'],
        'text':['hello ab nice to meet you','hey I will be happy to meet you']
}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(',' in row['ticker_like']):
        values= row['ticker_like'].split(',')
        df['ticker_like'].replace(row['ticker_like'],values[0], inplace=True)
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [row['dt'],values[1],row['text']] 
# Print the output.
print(df)
```